# How to ship a full suspension bike frame without the shock?

Tags: mountain-bike

I'm shipping a full suspension bike frame without a shock and I'm looking for a good way to ensure the seat post tube doesn't get banged up by the rear shock mount or triangle. In the past I have zip tied them together but this frame is in excellent condition and I'd prefer it to not get scratched up in transit. I have seen the plastic dummy bars, but I don't know what they're called and can't find one locally anyway. Does anyone have any suggestions for keeping the two halves stable in transit?

Comment: Tape corrugated cardboard around the parts that might come into contact, then tape them together so they don't move around?

Comment: Could you remove the lower pivot to separate them entirely, then wrap them both and tie together once they are thoroughly padded and protected? May be able to ship in a smaller box this way as well.

Answer (score 8):

Besides all the other protection measures of wrapping and padding the bike's tubes, you can make a "fake shock" of wood. That is, measure the distance between the shock's eyelets, cut/saw a wooden "stick" from a board so that it fits inside the frame, drill two holes on its ends, and mount that stick instead of the shock. The same trick is used to place wooden blocks in frame's/fork's dropouts when the frame is transported without wheels so side side loads do not bend them.

The wood is an excellent material for the task, as it is firm and is easy to work on with almost any type of saw even by a person with little experience. Size tolerances can also be very wide — it won't make a difference if your fake shock is 5mm shorter/longer and ugly as hell.

Comment: Yep. A short length of 1" x 2" from the local hardware or construction store's cutoff bin will do. They might not even charge you for it.

Comment: Just attach some kind of warning to the bicycle so that no-one may be tempted to ride with the 'shock'.